# Selecting item2 on page 1 returns item1 on page2

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am dynamically creating rows and tables from a database to display a list of read-only items. When one of these items is clicked, the page should reload to a different window and display the relevant results related to the clicked item.

I have 99% of this working, however when I click the first row (let's say "item1" the next window reflects undefined. When I click the second row ("item2") the window reflects the results of item1. When I click the third row ("item3") the window reflects the results of item2.

The most I understand is that I may not be storing the variables correctly.

My closest guess is this may be a solution for queryString, however I am not sure how or where to implement it.

I have provided all relevant code commented for the sake of anyone else who may have this problem.

```
var customApp = function(){

// Establish Variables
var salonName
var salonDomainLink
var salonAddress
var salonPhoneNumber
var salonSelection

// Queries Salons class
var query1 = new Parse.Query("Salons");
query1.find({
    success: function(results) {

    // Changes search results from JSON Object to ?something readable?
        var searchResults = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(results))

        // Loops through every result and creates variables with each specific result
        for ( var i in searchResults) {
            salonName = searchResults[i].name;
            salonDomainLink = searchResults[i].domainLink;

            // Creates a new row for each item in table
            var newrow = $('<tr>').text('').appendTo('#searchTable');

            // Adds a cell for each salonName in row
            var nameCell = $('<td>').text(salonName).appendTo(newrow);

            // Adds an id of the salon name + 'Id' to each row
            var cellId = nameCell.attr("id", salonName.replace(/\s+/g, '') + "Id")

            // Changes class of each cell
            nameCell.addClass("text-left font-w600 text-primary");
        }

        // Passes clicked salon name to a variable for use on another page
        $('#searchTable tr td').click(function(){

            // Acquires text value of the specific td of tr
            salonSelection = $(this)[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue

            // Saves the variable to local storage (can be retrieved with "localStorage.salonSelection")
            delete localStorage.salonSelection;
            window.localStorage.salonSelection = salonSelection;
            window.location = 'base_pages_schedule_1.html';
        });
    },
    error: function(error) {
        alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message + ". Please contact Support.");
    }
});

query1.equalTo("name", localStorage.salonSelection);
query1.find({
    success: function(results) {
        var searchResults = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(results))
        // Loops through every result and creates variables with each specific result
        for ( var i in searchResults) {
            window.localStorage.salonName = searchResults[i].name;
            window.localStorage.salonDomainLink = searchResults[i].domainLink;
            window.localStorage.salonAddress = searchResults[i].address;
            window.localStorage.salonPhoneNumber = searchResults[i].phoneNumber;
        }
    },
    error: function(error) {
        alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message + ". Please contact Support.");
    }
});
$('#salon-name').text(localStorage.salonName);
$('#salon-address').text(localStorage.salonAddress);
$('#salon-phone-number').text(localStorage.salonPhoneNumber):};
```

Comment: not sure what you are wanting in localStorage. Your `for` look overwrites the storage key values in each iteration so only the last item returned from `find()` will be stored

Comment: The goal was to take the '.click()' function results and make a new query based on that result so that I could display the relevant information on the next page. So user clicks Salon2 (or any options) on page 1 and page 2 reflects the information queried from the database for Salon2.

Comment: ok...but normlly that result from server wouldn't be array if you only want one item

Comment: So in the first query I am querying a list of items for the user to choose from, and then after the user chooses a single item and loads up the next window I am querying again but with the constraint of the single object the user selected. I intend to take several items from that object. There may be a more efficient way do that judging from your comment below, though.

Comment: probably is. Play with it a bit more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`query.find()` is asynchronous so it won't set new values until after you set the `text()` in the dom

Move the dom updates into your `find()` success callback

```
query1.find({
    success: function(results) {
        var searchResults = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(results))
        // process results

        // then update dom
        $('#salon-name').text(localStorage.salonName);

    },
    error: function(error) {
        alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message + ". Please contact Support.");
    }
});
```

Also note that your `for` loop is rewriting a new value to the storage keys on each iteration of the loop so only the last one gets stored. Not sure what your storage objectives are here

Comment: This helped fix my problem. I knew it was a basic issue but I could just not figure out that the placement was what was screwing me up. 

I am also aware that the 'for' loop was rewriting the local variables, I was just playing around with exactly how localStorage worked in different scenarios.

If you have any other comments about the process I am using, I would love to hear them! Either way, thank you for the assistance!

Comment: also simple to store a whole object .... `localStorage.setItem('some_object', JSON.stringify(theObject))`...then use JSON.parse()...when you retrieve

Comment: I hadn't thought of making localStorage items entire objects, that's a great idea!